# Wrong text for beta badge on meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

There is a wrong text for beta badge on meta. It says "Actively participated in the Stack Overflow private beta", shouldn't that say "Actively participated *Meta* Stack Overflow private beta"?

Comment: See also http://meta.superuser.com/q/4282/101850

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, that badge should probably just be removed, since there was never really a Beta for MetaSO.

Comment: It seems, that beta badge was removed from Meta.

Comment: And the Precognitive badge.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Meta was ever in Beta. It was a direct launch on Jeff whim if I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Meta was created directly from Stack Overflow. Users who started using it early, even got to keep their user-ids from Stack Overflow.